# obtain output of command to parse in in c / MacOSX

Tags: c++, c, shell, macos

I'm working on a Command Line app to help me on launchd tasks to know if a task is running by returning a BOOL, the problem comes when i need to do a command line and obtain the output for further parsing.

i'm coding it in C/C++ so i can't use NSTask for it, any ideas on how to achieve the goal?

The Command

```
sudo launchctl list -x [job_label]
```

If i use system(), i'm unable to get the output so in further research I came with popen(), but no success there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a pipe from which you can read the output of the program. This will involve using `pipe`, `fork`, `exec*`, and maybe even `dup`. There's a good tutorial on [the linux documentation project](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the home-brew way with `pipe()`, `fork()`, and the `exec*()` family of functions, or you could use `popen()` if its constraints meet your requirements.